# Is there any way to identify user within execute() method of a GeoServer process?

Tags: geoserver, wps, authentication

After processing of data within WPS I want to place the result in a folder with a name that corresponds to username, then to send the user URL to access it. To do that, I need a mechanism to determine username within `execute()` method of my process class. How to do that?

Comment: It may be worth asking on the GeoServer Dev list if you don't get an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Groan on the geoserver user list described this procedure which was confirmed by @xtreye:

Authentication:

```
user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

To get the user name:

```
user.getName()
```

Comment: @xtreye I'd still try it out as part of researching an answer. Depends on the logging. As long as the processing result can be associated to a user then it is just a matter of traversing through processes and associated results and placing them in the correct folders.

Comment: @xtreye thanks! I have forwarded the question to the geoserver users list. If someone answers it there I will update the above answer accordingly.

Comment: @xtreye I will proceed to streamline the answer above. Feel free to contribute.